# Leaflet.Draw color while drawing

Tags: leaflet.draw

I'm using a color picker to choose the color of an object to draw it with Leaflet.Draw but cannot find where.

```
    $("#txtAPColor").on('change', function(){
        colorSelectPoi=$("#txtAPColor").value;
    });

   var circle_options = {
        stroke: true,
        color: colorSelectPoi,
        weight: 4,
        opacity: 0.5,
        fill: true,
        fillColor: null, //same as color by default
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        clickable: true
      };
     new L.Draw.Circle(map, circle_options).enable();
```

Comment: I haven't been able to figure this out, how to draw using a different color while drawing with the control... I will keep trying a little more...

Comment: First off, make sure both accept the same value, #hexCode like: #FFFFFF. Second, may be you need to redraw the shape.

Comment: from the on change block

Answer (score 5):

I have solved the problem with the following code:

```
var optionColorSelected = '#000'
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (event) {
    event.layer.options.color = optionColorSelected;
    var layer = event.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});
```

You just have to update the variable *optionColorSelected* with the color you choose.
I hope I can help you.